# Long Lived Page Access token expired after a couple of hours using PHP SDK 3.2.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, access-token, facebook-access-token

Remove offline_access permission is enabled in my app advanced settings;

I first call the following function:

```
public function app_login( $url_redirect=null ) {
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => APP_ID,
            'secret' => APP_SECRET,
            'cookie' => true,
            'fileUpload' => true
        ));

        //check if redirection url specified
        if( $url_redirect != null )
            $go_to = $url_redirect;
        else
            $go_to = 'APP_URL';


        $loginParams = array(

            'scope'         => 'publish_stream,user_activities,user_checkins,user_interests,user_location,manage_pages,email,read_insights,read_stream',
            'redirect_uri'  => $go_to
        );
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( $loginParams );

        if ( ! $facebook->getUser() ) {

            echo '<script>window.top.location = "' . $login_url . '";</script>';

            return true;
        }

        return $facebook;

    }
```

returning a value called $facebook,
then I ask for the extended user token with the following calls:

```
$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
$extended_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

save $extended_token in my database, then get user pages with

```
$pages = @json_decode( FB_Actions::file_get_contents_curl( 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $facebook->getUser() . '/accounts?access_token=' . $extended_token ) );
```

and save the page tokens in my database.
When I try to use those tokens later on, I get a reply saying that the token expired.

Does anybody have an idea of what my problem is?

Comment: it's a facebook bug https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/341793929223330?browse=search_5039d4c8e833c2834339143 . Now i'm trying to find someone who found a way around

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and found solution here - [Getting long-lived access token with setExtendedAccessToken() returns short lived token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196958/getting-long-lived-access-token-with-setextendedaccesstoken-returns-short-live)

```
// ask for the extended token and get it from session ...
$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
$access_token = $_SESSION["fb_".FB_APP_ID."_access_token"];
// now set it into the facebook object ....
$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
// now our fb object will use the new token as usual ...
$accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

Also use facebook debug tool - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug