# Getting long-lived access token with setExtendedAccessToken() returns short lived token

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I try to get extended long-lived access token with

```
$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

After looking SDK I found that setExtendedAccessToken() function is setting long-lived access token in

```
protected static $kSupportedKeys =
array('state', 'code', 'access_token', 'user_id');
```

with

```
$this->setPersistentData(
  'access_token', $response_params['access_token']
);
```

and getAccessToken() is returning short-lived access token from

```
protected $accessToken
```

so what is the purpose of setExtendedAccessToken() since it does not return anything?

Comment: I also hope that someone could give any helpful answer to that question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@Julian. Thank you so much for the inspiration here.
I was able to make this work without changing any of the core FB api files.

What happens is, the `setExtendedAccessToken` call sends the value to `setPersistentData` which then sends it into session via `constructSessionVariableName`.

So if we get it out of session, and then set it into the facebook object, we're all set.

Here is my code:

```
// ask for the extended token and get it from session ...
$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
$access_token = $_SESSION["fb_".FB_APP_ID."_access_token"];
// now set it into the facebook object ....
$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
// now our fb object will use the new token as usual ...
$accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

Comment: Do you have cross browser version for this? that session is not set sometimes, for example using Mac OSX Opera

Answer (score 5):

After further attempt to poke around `base_facebook.php`, I have discovered the following:

- `setExtendedAccessToken();` will exchange a short-lived access token and Facebook *will* return a proper extended access token.
- `setExtendedAccessToken();` saves this in the persistent data cache, but this doesn't mean `getAccessToken();` can access it, because `getAccessToken();` doesn't query the persistent cache. Furthermore, the class seems to treat the persistent data as a "failsafe", and only uses it if all other attempts to retrieve data have failed (that is, after checking `signed_request`, and parsing a `code`).
- In our case, the access token returned via `setExtendedAccessToken();` is the most recent access token, so I hacked in a fix. Add the following line at the bottom of `setExtendedAccessToken();`

  `// Also set the publically accessible access token value to this new extended token`

  `$this->accessToken = $response_params['access_token'];`
- **Caveat**: Even though we now have the new extended access token, subsequent queries to Facebook to retrieve an access token (e.g. after a page refresh) will return the same old short-lived access token. *facepalm*
- Even after the user logs out (thus causing the short-lived token to expire), and logs back in, Facebook will again return a short-lived access token.
- However, even though this is the case, `setExtendedAccessToken();` will return the same extended access token you retrieved earlier. This token is still usable to query user information.

So, this looks like a Facebook bug, as much as I hate saying it. We can get around it with the hack I have detailed above, and any subsequent calls to fetch an access token will just return a short-lived access token, which can be exchanged again and again for the same extended access token.

---

**Original Answer**

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9035036/122353), the new access token is saved in the persistent data (as you have also indicated in your question), and can be accessed via `$facebook->getAccessToken();`.

Two relevant notes:

- [This page](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) also mentions that when the short-lived access token is exchanged for an extended access token, the token itself **may or may not change**, although the expiry time should have updated to reflect the longer expiration. Perhaps when you call `$facebook->getAccessToken();`, you are merely getting the same token back, but its expiration has changed?
- The call to exchange a short-lived access token for an extended one can only be made *once a day per user*. I don't know why this is, and I don't know whether this counter is reset if a user decides to de-authorize your app and re-authorize.

From the Facebook documentation:

> When a user visits your site with an existing, valid, short-lived user access_token, you have the option to extend the expiration time of that access token. **Our platform will only extend the expiration time once per day**, so even if a user revists your site multiple times a day, the token will be extended the first time requested. *(emphasis mine)*

I believe this is the case because sloppy programmers will call `$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();` at every possible opportunity, in the hopes of always retrieving an extended access token. (Instead of the *preferred* behaviour, which would be only calling `$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();` if what you currently have is a short-lived access token -- but how would you even tell unless you've saved the expiration date, which in and of itself isn't that reliable...!)

My assumption is that if a user de-authorizes the app, or the token otherwise invalidates, the limit will reset, and you will be able to once again retrieve an extended access token when passing in a short-lived access token. However, this requires further testing, so please take this paragraph with a grain of salt.

Comment: Julian H. Lam it seems to work when I don't go through the facebook chrome, maybe they meant it to work with web pages that use facebook and not the web apps that are displayed inside the fb chrome.