# Facebook Access-Token for ever?

Tags: facebook, token

is it possible to create a Facebook Access-Token which lasts for ever?

Actually mine ends after 2 hours :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, "offline_access" has been deprecated/removed (https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/).

You can only get a long living token which lasts for about 60 days. The easiest way is to use the PHP SDK, there is a function called "setExtendedAccessToken" to achieve this.

Also, see those threads:

- [Getting long-lived access token with setExtendedAccessToken() returns short lived token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196958/getting-long-lived-access-token-with-setextendedaccesstoken-returns-short-live)
- [Facebook 60 day access token and Deprecated Offline_Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329564/facebook-60-day-access-token-and-deprecated-offline-access)

Comment: may i ask why the downvote? please explain so i can improved my answer if something is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

It depends for what you want to do with the Acess Token.

If you want an acess token to access an user data. You can use the "setExtendedAccessToken" method, how the luschn said in his answer.

But, if you want an acess token to access some public information, like an a feed from a public group, or a page. So you can uses an App Access Token. Which you gets here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/